# bieten - für oder auf

Tags: verb, preposition

> Lisa bietet auf eine Puppe im Internet.

vs

> Lisa bietet für eine Puppe im Internet.

Ist "für" hier möglich bzw eventuell in manchen Gegenden gebräuchlich? Ich kenne nur die Version mit "auf" - "für" klingt hier für mich falsch.

*Is "für" here valid or even commonly used in some areas? I only know the version with "auf" - "für" sounds wrong to me.*

---

> Lisa bietet 5 € für eine Puppe im Internet.

Comment: Hilfe für die Tags ist gern gesehen; sollen/dürfen/können Fragen hier komplett in Deutsch gestellt werden?

Comment: Es ist erlaubt komplett auf Deutsch zu fragen.

Comment: Die Sprache auf der du fragst bestimmt im Übrigen die Sprache der Antwort. Fragst du auf Deutsch, gibt's eine Antwort auf Deutsch. Fragst Du auf Englisch, gibt's eine auf Englisch. Das soll auch anderen Nutzern, die auf die Frage stoßen die Möglichkeit geben, die Antwort zu verstehen.

Answer (score 4):

*Auf etwas bieten* tut man meist bei einer Auktion, bei der der Höchstbietende das zu Ersteigernde erhält.

*Für etwas bieten*, gibt es nicht. Es gibt stattdessen *etwas für etwas bieten*. Man bietet einen Austausch von zwei Objekten an, häufig auf Flohmärkten zu beobachten.

*Ich biete Ihnen 10€ für das Bild.*

[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bieten) hat weitere Beispiele.

Answer (score 4):

> bieten – *für* oder *auf*?

Es kommt darauf an. Das Verb [*bieten*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bieten) kann grob in zwei Bedeutungsgruppen eingeteilt werden, und für jede Gruppe werden üblicherweise andere Präpositionen verwendet.

#### Bedeutungsgruppe 1

Wenn *bieten* im Sinne von *zusichern*, *geben*, *gewähren* verwendet wird, dann steht üblicherweise vor dem Angebotenen die Präposition *für* und vor dem Gegenwert keine Präposition:

> Lisa bietet fünf Euro *für* die Puppe im Internet.

Hier würde ich denken, dass im Internet eine Puppe *verkauft* wird und Lisa bereit ist, *für* diese Puppe fünf Euro zu bezahlen.

#### Bedeutungsgruppe 2

Wenn *bieten* im Sinne von *ein Angebot bei einer Versteigerung machen* verwendet wird, dann steht üblicherweise vor dem Angebotenen die Präposition *auf* (siehe z. B. [Bedeutung 6 im DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bieten#d-1-6)):

> Lisa bietet (*für*)* fünf Euro *auf* die Puppe im Internet.
>
> <sup>* Ich persönlich würde vor dem Gegenwert die Präposition *für* setzen. Da dies andere Sprecher als unüblich empfinden, habe ich es in Klammern gesetzt.</sup>

Hier würde ich denken, dass die Puppe im Internet *versteigert* wird und Lisa bereit ist, (*für*) fünf Euro *auf* die Puppe mitzubieten.

Comment: Hast du zufällig ein Beispiel, wo *für etw. auf etw. bieten* verwendet wird? Ich hätte eher *etw. auf etw. bieten* erwartet, ohne *für*.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus, hm, interessant ... Ich stimme zu, dass der Beispielsatz auch ohne *für* in meinen Ohren nicht schief klingt. Allerdings würde ich bei *mitbieten* das *für* vermissen: „Er will aufs Gemälde *für* 500 € mitbieten.“ Und genaugenommen ist mit *bieten* in einer Versteigerung ja *mitbieten* gemeint.

Comment: Tut mir leid, aber zum ersten mal musste ich hier downvoten. Den zweiten von Dir vorgestellten Beispielssatz halte ich für 'falsch' in dem Sinne, dass niemand ihn ohne das Gefühl sagen würde, sich möglicherweise nicht korrekt ausgedrückt zu haben. Wie @amadeusamadeus kenne ich 'bieten auf' ohne weiteres Präpositionalobjekt. Das Objekt von 'bieten für' im Kontext 'Versteigerung' (!) kann in meiner Grammatik nur der bebotene Gegenstand sein, nicht der gebotene Geldbetrag. Bei 'für Ihr Geld wird bei uns einiges geboten', einer werbetypischen Konstruktion, lägen die Dinge anders.

Comment: @RalfJoerres, die Antwort aus Geschmacksgründen abzuwerten, obwohl es so auch im Wörterbuch steht (und somit offenbar von einer genügend großen Anzahl von Sprechern verwendet wird), finde ich sehr grenzwertig! Schauen Sie mal Bedeutung 6 von https://www.dwds.de/wb/bieten an. Vielleicht überlegen Sie es sich nochmal und ändern Ihre Wahl? Nicht alles was einem persönlich missfällt, ist auch falsch und daher abzuwerten.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich So, wie ich es verstanden habe, akzeptieren alle *bieten auf* + Ware, aber nicht mit *für* + Geldbetrag zusammen. Und letzteres erwähnt das Wörterbuch auch nicht.

Comment: (Also außer in der Bedeutung *wenn du mir fünf Euro gibst*, *für fünf Euro mache ich das*. Aber das ist ja ein ganz anderes Szenario.)

Comment: Herr Friedrich, hallo! Ich muss nicht noch einmal schreiben, was David Vogt geschrieben hat. Warum ändern Sie nicht einfach Ihre Antwort und nehmen das "(für)" wieder raus, das offensichtlich nicht nur mir seltsam erscheint und durch kein Wörterbuch belegt ist?

Answer (score 1):

Für die angefragten Sätze scheint es regionale, vielleicht auch nationale Gebrauchsvarianten zu geben. Ich kann nur für mich sprechen: Ich komme aus Westdeutschland, genauer aus dem Ruhrgebiet.

Damit es nicht zu unübersichtlich wird, hier die Kurzversion:

- '**(einen Betrag) auf etwas bieten**' ist die Standardformulierung bei Versteigerungen. Es ist 'Versteigerungsjargon' und abseits dessen nicht üblich.
- '**jemandem einen Betrag (für etwas) bieten / anbieten**' ist die Standardformulierung für Verkaufsverhandlungen.

Das heißt: Sobald *bieten* zusammen mit *auf* vorkommt, handelt es sich um eine Versteigerung. Wenn *bieten* mit einem Dativobjekt (jemandem) vorkommt, handelt es sich normalerweise **nicht** um eine Versteigerung.

Von den mehreren Objekten der Standardformulierungen sind einzelne oder mehrere in speziellen Kontexten weglassbar. Im Einzelnen:

1. bieten (ohne Objekt) = ein Gebot abgeben: *Hast du schon geboten?*
2. x (Euro) für etwas bieten: *Ich habe 15 Euro für das Fahrrad geboten.*
3. x (Euro) bieten: *Mein Limit war 20, aber ein anderer hat 25 geboten.*
4. jemandem x (Euro) für etwas bieten: *Mir hat jemand 10 Euro für mein altes Handy geboten.*
5. |akkusativischer Mengenausdruck (+ Geld)| bieten: *Ich habe nicht genug / zu wenig geboten.*
6. jemandem |akkusativisches Mengenausdruck (+ Geld)| bieten: *Später habe ich ihm noch mehr geboten*.
7. (|Mengenausdruck|) auf etwas bieten: *Ich habe es seit einer Woche bei Ebay eingestellt, aber bis jetzt hat keiner (etwas) darauf geboten.*
8. x (Euro) / auf etwas bieten: *Da hat doch tatsächlich jemand noch 25 Euro auf die alte Gurke geboten!*
9. jemandem x Euro für etwas bieten: *Er hat mir 40 Euro für mein altes Handy geboten.*

Eher auf Versteigerungen beschränkt sind die Konstruktionen 1 + 2 (+ 3) (+ 5) + 7 + 8, ausschließlich bei Verkaufsverhandlungen kommen die Konstruktionen 4 und 9 vor. Möchte man eine ähnliche Bedeutung wie bei den Versteigerungssätzen bezogen auf eine Verkaufsverhandlung ausdrücken, muss man das mit dem Verb 'anbieten' tun:

2' *Ich habe 15 Euro für das Fahrrad angeboten.*

Noch 'natürlicher' wäre der Satz mit Empfänger-Dativobjekt:

2'' *Ich habe ihm 15 Euro für das Fahrrad geboten / angeboten.*

Comment: Jetzt schauen Sie sich mal ihren Punkt 7 genauer an, wo es darum geht *auf etwas zu bieten*. Im Beispiel steht „... hat keiner etwas darauf geboten“. Das ist die gleiche Konstruktion wie „... hat fünf Euro auf die Puppe geboten“. Dennoch haben Sie meine Antwort wegen dieser Konstruktion abgewertet.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich: Das stimmt einerseits, andererseits sind diese '5 Euro' kein Mengenausdruck (Indefinitpronomen) sondern ein Preisgebot. Ich hatte mich in Ihrem Beispiel vor allem an dem 'für' gestört, das ich aus meiner regional geprägten Sprachkompetenz heraus ablehnen würde, zumal ich ein 'für-Objekt' immer dem angebotenen Gegenstand und nie dem Preis zuordnen würde. Könnte trotzdem sein, dass das anderswo so möglich ist Man sieht auch bei der Vielzahl der Varianten - es gibt wahrscheinlich noch mehr -, dass über richtig oder falsch hier nicht einfach zu entscheiden ist.

Answer (score -2):

Ich halte *"auf"* für falsch. Ich würde niemals sage, dass ich fünf Euro *auf* etwas biete. Ich biete fünf Euro *für* die Puppe.

Meiner Meinung nach ist daher nur diese Variante die einzig richtige:

> richtig: Lisa bietet 5 € **für** eine Puppe im Internet.

Die von dir vorgeschlagene Variante habe ich noch nie gehört.

> falsch: Lisa bietet 5 € **auf** eine Puppe im Internet.

Möglicherweise ist da aber wieder eines der unzähligen Beispiele für die Unterschiedlichkeiten der Varietäten der deutschen Sprache. (Ich lebe seit meiner Geburt im Osten Österreichs.)

Comment: Würdest du dann auch "Lisa bietet für eine Puppe" (also ohne die "5 €") sagen?

Comment: ("Lisa bietet 5 € auf eine Puppe" kenne ich aus dem Sprachgebrauch um mich herum - Nordbayern hauptsächlich - schon; allerdings eher "salopp gesprochen", weniger im "professionellem Bereich")

Comment: [Duden | bieten b)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bieten) "sie hat auf das Bild [5 000 Euro] geboten". Im Auktionszusammenhang ist das vollkommen richtig und üblich, das so zu sagen.

Comment: @DanielJour: Ja klar. Wie gesagt: "bieten auf etwas" habe ich noch nie gehört und kommt mir falsch vor.

Comment: @infinitezero: Das nehme ich so hin, aber "bieten auf" ist mir persönlich vollkommen unbekannt. Allerdings habe ich auch noch nie im Leben an einer Auktion teilgenommen.

Comment: [Ebay | Grundsatz zum Bieten](https://www.ebay.de/help/default/default/grundsatz-zum-bieten-auf-eigene-angebote?id=4353) nutzt als Online-Aktionshaus auch diese Formulierung.

Comment: Interessant in diesem Zusammenhang vielleicht auch die Wörter *aufbieten* und *Aufgebot*